# Simple Integration by substitution problem

Tags: calculus

I was given the following function:

$$\int e^x \tan(e^x+3)^4dx$$

and was requested to replace $e^x=u$.

Isn't the answer $$\int u\cdot \tan(u+3)^4du$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you got an extra $u$ it should just be $\int \tan(u+3)^4$ since $e^xdx$ gets replaced by $du$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something. In short, if $e^x = u$, then $e^x dx = du$, which you omitted.

It is also easier if you perform the $u$-substitution $e^x + 3 = u$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^x+3=u\implies du=e^x\ dx$

$$\implies\int e^x\tan^4(e^x+3)\ dx=\int\tan^4u\ du$$

$$=\int\tan^2u(\sec^2u-1)\ du$$

$$=\int\tan^2u\sec^2u\ du-\int(\sec^2u-1)\ du$$

Comment: The op has asked for $u=e^x$ substitution.